# Preserve dataframe style when exporting notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

How can I preserve the DataFrame style which I see in the Jupyter Notebook when I export the notebook to HTML?

I convert it like this:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html <name>.ipynb
```

When I have converted it I only get an "ugly" DataFrame grid, and not the nice formatting as I see in the notebook.